# PlayOnLinux fails to install MS Office (weird EULA blank window)

Tags: software-installation, playonlinux, microsoft-office, crossover

I'm trying to install MS Office 2010 with PlayOnLinux on Lubuntu 18.04.

The installation process runs for more than 30 min with no results. An EULA window pops up, but it happens to mostly blank (no ok button, no option for tab+accept).

[image]

I used Wine through the terminal and accepted the EULA, but an error message appears, saying it couldn't be installed.

Finally, I decided to try CrossOver and I succeeded installing MS Office 2010.

What might be wrong with PlayOnLinux then?

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to fix it? :/ I'm relatively new to Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the same like this....

1) Playonlinux - wine manager - 86x - install wine 3.8

2) Create new 32 bit virtual drive with wine 3.8

*Note: If you getting error while creating virtual drive; then

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt install wine32

then try to create 32 bit virtual drive again*

3) In that virtual drive - pol component setup - install riched20, dotnet20 & msxml6

4) Install ms office 2010 setup from "non listed" option. (Do not install from the given list)

Comment: Just running :
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt install wine32`
and restarting the usual PlayOnLinux installation worked for me.